# Data frame assigning

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

im back today with a new question.

Already looked for the answer but all the answers im reading are requiring some big previous knowledge which I dont have at the moment.

The issue I want to solve is how can I automatically assign a name to a value depending on a variable of a data frame.

So Imagine I have a Data frame of ChickWeight in the package datasets.

There are 50 Chicks in the Data Frame, and there are several rows for each Chick depending on the time.

I want to Assign something like this but with all the Chicks. WITHOUT having to manually type in all of the 50 of them.

```
Chick1 <- ChickWeight[which(ChickWeight$Chick == 1),]
...
...
Chick50 <- ChickWeight[which(ChickWeight$Chick == 50),]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Put it in a list of dataframes using `split()`

Comment: Also, it seems like you're trying to do something that's a bad idea. Why do you want to assign 50 `data.frame`s like this?

Comment: Dont know why would you titter? Regarding the idea what would you advice if I want to analyze each chick differently?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It would seem `split`, `aggregate` and `by` (or their combination) would do the trick. Check the spelling in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they mentioned in the comments, for a list of data frames:

```
ldf <- split(ChickWeight, ChickWeight$Chick)
```

Then to access an element of the list, for instance the data frame for the chick 20:

```
ldf$`20`
```

If you want to have separated objects for each data frame, unlist the list of data frames:

```
list2env(ldf, .GlobalEnv)
```

To access the data frame:

```
`20`
```

If we don't want numbers as data frame names we can create a new column `ChickWeight$id`adding the prefix `Chick_` and then proceed as we did before:

```
ChickWeight$id <- paste0("Chick_", ChickWeight$Chick)
# List of data frames
ldf <- split(ChickWeight, ChickWeight$id)
# Separated objects
list2env(ldf, .GlobalEnv)
```

To access a data frame, for instance: `Chick_20`

Comment: Thats pefect! Thank you! One question if you dont mind..
 d$`20`
That line of code is giving me "NULL" when I run it....  but when I use list2env works perfectly.
How does that work? Thank you very much

Comment: Another one if you dont mind? How can I rename all of the data frames so instead of having this name `10` they are Chick_10? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @TomasAlonsoRehor To you first comment, it was a typo I corrected. To your second comment, I expanded my answer so every data frame name is preceded by `Chick_` . Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: @TomasAlonsoRehor My answer provided a different way of doing the same thing. Please check my assigning function if you ever need to assign lots of variables.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to create exactly what you are looking for. Batch assigning was a bit of a challenge for the n00b I am.

```
df<-ChickWeight

#PREPARING VARIABLE NAMES

df$Chick<-paste("Chick_",df$Chick,sep="");
df$Chick<-as.character(factor(df$Chick, levels=unique(df$Chick)))

#FUNCTION TO BE ABLE TO BATCH ASSIGN

assign_ouistiti<-function(NAMES, VALUES) {mapply(assign, NAMES, VALUES, MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv));invisible()}

#PRODUCE ALL THE VARIABLES YOU WANTED

assign_ouistiti(names(split(df,df$Chick)),split(df,df$Chick))
```

You can now access the data about a chick directly:

```
> Chick_9
    weight Time   Chick Diet
96      42    0 Chick_9    1
97      51    2 Chick_9    1
98      59    4 Chick_9    1
99      68    6 Chick_9    1
100     85    8 Chick_9    1
101     96   10 Chick_9    1
102     90   12 Chick_9    1
103     92   14 Chick_9    1
104     93   16 Chick_9    1
105    100   18 Chick_9    1
106    100   20 Chick_9    1
107     98   21 Chick_9    1
```